# Collapse data frame into single row and creating new columns based on row R

Tags: r, matrix, rows, reshape

I have a data frame with object names and a list of statistical moments for that object, like this:

```
Object   Mean   IQR   Skew  
   x        1     1      1
   y        2     2      2  
   z        3     3      3
```

What i want is to for each row create columns with the statistical moments and the object name prefixed. Like so:

`xMean xIQR xSkew yMean yIQR ySkew zMean zIQR zSkew
   1     1   1     2      2    2    3      3    3`

In essence what I need is to collapse a data frame to a single row such that it list all statistical moments on a single line as i'll have many rows like the final one but a finite set of columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: How about `u <- unlist(df[-1]); names(u) <- chartr("123", "xyz", names(u)); u`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
 df1$id <- 1
 reshape(df1, idvar="id", timevar="Object", direction="wide")[-1]
  #  Mean.x IQR.x Skew.x Mean.y IQR.y Skew.y Mean.z IQR.z Skew.z
  #1      1     1      1      2     2      2      3     3      3
```

Or  using `dcast`, `melt` from `reshape2`

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(melt(df1, id.var=c('id', 'Object')), id~..., value.var='value')[-1]
 #   x_Mean x_IQR x_Skew y_Mean y_IQR y_Skew z_Mean z_IQR z_Skew
 #1      1     1      1      2     2      2      3     3      3
```

Or  using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

  df1 %>% 
      gather(Var, Val, Mean:Skew) %>% 
      unite(VarNew,Object, Var, sep="") %>%
      spread(VarNew, Val) %>%
      select(-id)
  #    xIQR xMean xSkew yIQR yMean ySkew zIQR zMean zSkew
  #1    1     1     1    2     2     2    3     3     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Object = c("x", "y", "z"), Mean = 1:3, IQR = 1:3, 
 Skew = 1:3), .Names = c("Object", "Mean", "IQR", "Skew"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe something like

```
setNames(unlist(data.frame(t(df[-1]))), paste0(rep(df[, 1], each = nrow(df)), names(df[, -1])))
# xMean  xIQR xSkew yMean  yIQR ySkew zMean  zIQR zSkew 
#     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```